# ActivityNotFoundException despite the activity being registered in the manifest file

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application that has multiple packages and for a particular activity it throws the ActivityNotFoundException....Can someone point out what is wrong with my code......
*the package of the activity is com.example.neo.smsapp.IFTT*

**The logcat produces following lines**

```
*FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: com.example.neo.smsapp, PID: 7320
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.neo.smsapp/com.example.neo.smsapp.IFTT.CancelAnAlarmActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)                                                                      
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)                                                                      
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
at com.example.neo.smsapp.SetuppageActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(SetuppageActivity.java:239)*
```

**This is the setuppage activity (Main activity)**

```
package com.example.neo.smsapp;

/**
 * Created by Neo on 04/02/2017.
 */

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class SetuppageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String mNumber;
    EditText mEditTextNumber;
    EditText mEditTextMessage;
    private String mContactdisplayName;
    private long mInterval;
    private String mMessage;
    private String mFrequency;
    Button mButtonContact;
    Button mDatePickUp;
    Button mTimePickUp;
    Button mConfirm;
    RadioButton mOneTime, mFifteenMinuets, mHalfHour, mHourR, mHalfDay, mDaily, mWeekly, mMonthly, mYearly;
    private int mHour;
    private int mMinutes;
    private int mSeconds;

    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    private int mCurrentYear;
    private int mCurrentMonth;
    private int mCurrentDay;
    private int mCurrentHour;
    private int mCurrentMinute;

    DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog;
    TimePickerDialog mTimePickerDialog;
    Calendar c;
    private static SetuppageActivity mMainActivity;

    //AlarmManager am;
    //PendingIntent pi;
    private int mId;
    private boolean isOneTime = false;
    private PendingIntentsDataSource mDatasource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setuppage);
        mMainActivity = this;
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mButtonContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonContact);
        mEditTextNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
        mDatePickUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDatePickup);
        mTimePickUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTimePickup);
        mConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConfirm);
        mEditTextMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
        mOneTime = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.oneTime);
        mOneTime.setOnClickListener(this);
        mFifteenMinuets = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.fifteenMinutes);
        mFifteenMinuets.setOnClickListener(this);
        mHalfHour = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.halfHour);
        mHalfHour.setOnClickListener(this);
        mHourR = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hour);
        mHourR.setOnClickListener(this);
        mHalfDay = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.halfDay);
        mHalfDay.setOnClickListener(this);
        mDaily = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.daily);
        mDaily.setOnClickListener(this);
        mWeekly = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.weekly);
        mWeekly.setOnClickListener(this);
        mMonthly = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.monthly);
        mMonthly.setOnClickListener(this);
        mYearly = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Yearly);
        mEditTextNumber.setText("");
        mEditTextMessage.setText("");

        //create/open the database
        mDatasource = new PendingIntentsDataSource(this);
        mDatasource.open();

        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCurrentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mCurrentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mCurrentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mCurrentHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mCurrentMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        mButtonContact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
        mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mCurrentYear, mCurrentMonth,
                mCurrentDay);
        mTimePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, mCurrentHour, mCurrentMinute, true);
        // add a click listener to the button
        mDatePickUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                //DialogFragment df = new DialogFragment();
                //FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                mDatePickerDialog.show();
                //df.show(manager, tag)
            }
        });

        mTimePickUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                //DialogFragment df = new DialogFragment();
                //FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                mTimePickerDialog.show();
                //df.show(manager, tag)
            }
        });

        mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mMessage = mEditTextMessage.getText().toString();
                mNumber = mEditTextNumber.getText().toString();
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinutes);
                c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                //c.
                //c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
                c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                /*AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);*/
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SendSMSAlarmService.class);
                i.putExtra("com.example.neo.smsapp.number", mNumber);
                i.putExtra("com.example.neo.smsapp.message", mMessage);
                i.putExtra("com.example.neo.smsapp.frequency", mFrequency);

                /*final int*/
                mId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                i.putExtra("com.example.neo.smsapp.id", mId);
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), mId, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                if (isOneTime == false) {
                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), mInterval, pi);
                    addToDatabase(true);
                }
                if (isOneTime == true) {
                    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
                    addToDatabase(false);
                    /*TimerTask deleteAPendingIntentFromDatabaseForOneTimeAlarm = new TimerTask(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //if(isOneTime == true){
                                mDatasource.deletePendingIntent(mId);
                            //}
                        }

                    };
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(deleteAPendingIntentFromDatabaseForOneTimeAlarm, c.getTimeInMillis());*/
                }


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your SMS has been scheduled...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //exit the app
                /*Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);*/
                //finish();
                Intent refresh = new Intent();
                refresh.setClassName("com.example.neo.smsapp", "com.example.neo.smsapp.SetuppageActivity");
                startActivity(refresh);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.setuppage, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            /*case R.id.menuCancelAnAlarm:
                Intent i = new Intent();
                //i.setClassName("co", "com.somitsolutions.android.smsscheduler.CancelAnAlarmActivity");
                i.setClassName(getComponentName().getPackageName(),"CancelAnAlarmActivity");
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                return true;*/
            case R.id.menuCancelAnAlarm:
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName("com.example.neo.smsapp","com.example.neo.smsapp.IFTT.CancelAnAlarmActivity");
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mDatasource.close();
        /*mEditTextMessage.setText("");
        mEditTextNumber.setText("");*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mDatasource.open();
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCurrentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mCurrentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mCurrentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mCurrentHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mCurrentMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        /*mEditTextMessage.setText("");
        mEditTextNumber.setText("");    */
        mDatasource.open();
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCurrentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mCurrentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mCurrentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mCurrentHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mCurrentMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        /*mEditTextMessage.setText("");
        mEditTextNumber.setText("");    */
        mDatasource.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        /*mEditTextMessage.setText("");
        mEditTextNumber.setText("");*/
        mDatasource.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //exit the app
        mDatasource.close();
        //finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);
        //android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            if (uri != null) {
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Identity.DISPLAY_NAME},
                            null, null, null);

                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        //mNumber = c.getString(0);
                        int type = c.getInt(1);
                        mEditTextNumber.setText(c.getString(0));
                        mContactdisplayName = c.getString(2);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;

                }
            };

    // the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    mHour = hourOfDay;
                    mMinutes = minute;
                    //updateDisplay();
                }
            };

    public static SetuppageActivity getMAinActivity() {
        return mMainActivity;
    }

    public String getNumberToSend() {
        return mNumber;
    }

    public String getSMSMessage() {
        return mMessage;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return mDay;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return mMonth;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return mYear;
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return mHour;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return mMinutes;
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        return mSeconds;
    }

    public PendingIntentsDataSource getDataSource() {
        //create/open the database
        return mDatasource;
    }
    //mDatasource = new PendingIntentsDataSource(this);
    //mDatasource.open();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if (v.equals(mOneTime)) {
            isOneTime = true;
            mFrequency = "Once";
        }
        if (v.equals(mFifteenMinuets)) {
            //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);
            mInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES;
            mFrequency = "15 mins";
            isOneTime = false;
            //c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        }
        if (v.equals(mHalfHour)) {
            //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pi);
            mInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR;
            mFrequency = "Half Hour";
            //c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            isOneTime = false;
        }
        if (v.equals(mHourR)) {
            //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pi);
            //c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            mInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR;
            mFrequency = "Hour";
            isOneTime = false;
        }
        if (v.equals(mHalfDay)) {
            //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, pi);
            //c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            mInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY;
            mFrequency = "Half Day";
            isOneTime = false;
        }
        if (v.equals(mDaily)) {
            //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
            //c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            mInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;
            mFrequency = "Daily";
            isOneTime = false;
        }
        if (v.equals(mWeekly)) {
            //int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            //c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), 7*24*60*60*1000, pi);
            mInterval = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            mFrequency = "Week";
            isOneTime = false;

        }
        if (v.equals(mMonthly)) {
            //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);*/
            isOneTime = false;
            mFrequency = "Month";
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            if ((month == Calendar.JANUARY) || (month == Calendar.MARCH) || (month == Calendar.MAY) || (month == Calendar.JULY) || (month == Calendar.AUGUST) || (month == Calendar.OCTOBER) || (month == Calendar.DECEMBER)) {
                mInterval = 31 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            }
            if ((month == Calendar.APRIL) || (month == Calendar.JUNE) || (month == Calendar.SEPTEMBER) || (month == Calendar.NOVEMBER)) {
                mInterval = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            }
            if (month == Calendar.FEBRUARY) {
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                if ((year % 4) == 0) {
                    mInterval = 29 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                }
                if ((year % 4) != 0) {
                    mInterval = 28 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                }

            }

        }
        if (v.equals(mYearly)) {
            //c.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), 365*24*60*60*1000, pi);
            mInterval = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            mFrequency = "Year";
            isOneTime = false;
        }
        //
    }

    private void addToDatabase(boolean isRepeated) {
        if (isRepeated == true) {

            SMSSchedulerPendingIntent newDatabeseEntry = mDatasource.createPendingIntents(mId, mHour, mMinutes, mSeconds, mYear, mMonth, mDay, mFrequency, mNumber, mContactdisplayName, mMessage);
        }
        if (isRepeated == false) {
            SMSSchedulerPendingIntent newDatabeseEntry = mDatasource.createPendingIntents(mId, mHour, mMinutes, mSeconds, mYear, mMonth, mDay, mFrequency, mNumber, mContactdisplayName, mMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest file**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SetuppageActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".CancelAnAlarmActivity"
            android:label="CancelAlarm"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".SendSMSAlarmService"/>
    </application>
```

Comment: did you try with com.example.neo.smsapp.IFTT.CancelAnAlarmActivity in menifest file.

Comment: you forgot this `com.example.neo.smsapp.IFTT.CancelAnAlarmActivity` activity

Comment: yes above both comment is help you

Comment: like  <activity android:name="com.example.neo.smsapp.IFTT.CancelAnAlarmActivity"
            android:label="CancelAlarm"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

Comment: try to uninstall and reinstall the app

Answer (score 1):

try with `com.example.neo.smsapp.IFTT.CancelAnAlarmActivity` in `manifest` file. Like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.neo.smsapp.IFTT.CancelAnAlarmActiv‌​ity"
          android:label="CancelAlarm" 
          android:screenOrientation="landscape">
</activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please define your activity in android manifest file.
Add this code to your android manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".SetuppageActivity"
            android:label="">
        </activity>
```